# Tkinter Table Creations and Placement

Tags: python, tkinter

I have used some code found here (https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-table-tutorial/   - under Python Tkinter Table with Scrollbar) to create and add data to a table in TKinter. However I am unable to move the table to the desired location.

The table object has been packed onto the grey box (table frame) separate from any other frame.

I am expecting the table be placed within the grey box as seen below:
[Current state of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHJz.png)

I have tried using .place() however that results in the following:
[.place() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZnos.jpg)

Below is code I have been practicing on. How would I place the table anywhere other than Top Centre?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title('Table Function')
window.geometry('1000x900')

table_values = {'Brize Norton': ['Teams', '39'],
                'Corsham': ['MS Word', '48'],
                'Corsford': ['MS Azure', '41'],
                'Halton': ['JIRA', '98']}

table_values2 = {'test1': ['Teams', '39'],
                 'test2': ['MS Word', '48'],
                 'test3': ['MS Azure', '41'],
                 'test4': ['JIRA', '98']}


def create_table():
    table_frame = Frame(master=window)
    table_frame.pack()

    # ---- scrollbar ----
    scroll_bar = Scrollbar(table_frame)
    scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    scroll_bar = Scrollbar(table_frame, orient='horizontal')
    scroll_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    Table_Object = ttk.Treeview(table_frame, yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

    Table_Object.pack()

    scroll_bar.config(command=Table_Object.yview)
    scroll_bar.config(command=Table_Object.xview)

    # ---- Define Columns ----
    Table_Object['columns'] = ('Station', 'Most Reported', 'Num')

    column_width = 150
    Table_Object.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
    Table_Object.column("Station", anchor=CENTER, width=column_width)
    Table_Object.column("Most Reported", anchor=CENTER, width=column_width)
    Table_Object.column("Num", anchor=CENTER, width=column_width)

    # Create Headings
    Table_Object.heading("#0", text="", anchor=CENTER)
    Table_Object.heading("Station", text="Station", anchor=CENTER)
    Table_Object.heading("Most Reported", text="Most Reported", anchor=CENTER)
    Table_Object.heading("Num", text="Num", anchor=CENTER)

    return table_frame, Table_Object


def add_table_values(values, table):
    """Adds the values to the table from a dictionary"""
    for loc in values.items():
        table.insert(parent='', index='end', text='', values=(loc[0], loc[1][0], loc[1][1]))


def delete_table_values(table):
    """Deletes the values to the table from a dictionary"""
    for i in table.get_children():
        table.delete(i)


table_frame, table_object = create_table()
delete_table_values(table_object)


def key_pressed(event):
    if event.char == 'p':
        delete_table_values(table_object)
        add_table_values(table_values, table_object)
    if event.char == 'q':
        delete_table_values(table_object)
        add_table_values(table_values2, table_object)


window.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)

window.mainloop()

"""Press 'P' to change from the first table to the second - Used as a test for changing values of the table"""
```

Comment: I see that you are setting your `table_frame`'s master to the tk window.  Is it possible you meant to set that to the frame that is your gray box?

Comment: You have used same variable `scroll_bar` for both the vertical and horizontal scrollbars.  Use separate variables for them.

Comment: @nrhoopes table_frame is the grey box